# Is there a way to use sockets to send/review data from a website?

Tags: python, sockets

Is there a way to use sockets to send/review data from a website like a Google search. Make it so you run a program and it searches some fixed value, then outputs the results in a Python shell.

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server = 'google.com'
port = 80
server_ip = socket.gethostbyname(server)
s.connect((server, port))
```

Comment: You _can_ do this with raw socket programming, but it's a whole lot easier to use a higher-level library like [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/) (or, if you can't install third-party software, [`urllib.request`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html). Or [a library specifically for Google searches](https://breakingcode.wordpress.com/2010/06/29/google-search-python/). Or just use a tool like [`curl`](https://curl.haxx.se/) instead of writing anything at all. Or [a tool specifically for Google searches](https://github.com/vinitkumar/googlecl).

Comment: More interesting question:  Is there a way to send/view data from a website *without* using sockets?

Comment: Is using sockets a requirement?  Or is searching a site and printing the results of that search the requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Try sending a HTTP GET request, e.g. bare minimum request to a HTTP 1.1 server:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()
s.connect(('httpbin.org', 80))

request = '\r\n'.join(('GET /get HTTP/1.1', 'Host: httpbin.org', '', ''))
s.send(request)
response = s.recv(1024)

>>> print(response)
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: keep-alive
Server: gunicorn/19.7.1
Date: Thu, 03 May 2018 22:40:59 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
X-Powered-By: Flask
X-Processed-Time: 0
Content-Length: 159
Via: 1.1 vegur

{
  "args": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Connection": "close", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org"
  }, 
  "origin": "220.233.14.203", 
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/get"
}
```

That's a lot more work than you need to do however. Consider using a library such as `requests`:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/get')
>>> print(r.text)
{
  "args": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", 
    "Connection": "close", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "python-requests/2.18.4"
  }, 
  "origin": "220.233.14.203", 
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/get"
}
```

Or the standard library [`urlopen()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen) function.